# How to use "nc_put_vars_float"

Tags: c++, netcdf

I don't know where was my wrong,here is code I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance.

First,I am preparing a data.

```
#define NDIMS 2
#define NX 6
#define NY 3

//initdata
  void makedata()
    {
         testdata = new float*[NY*NX];//init data
         for (int mv=0;mv<(NY*NX); mv++)
         {
             testdata[mv] = NULL;
         }
        for (int i=0; i<NX; i++)
        {
            testdata[i] = new float[NY];

            for (int j = 0; j<NY;j++)
            {
                int index = i*3 +j;
                testdata[i][j] = index;//add value
            }
        }
    }
```

and I write the data to file

```
   int n= 0;
   for (y = 0; y < NY; y++)
   {
       for (x = 0; x < NX; x++)
       {
           int index = y*3 +x;
           const float* data = testdata[index];

           size_t start[] = {n,0};//start
           size_t count[] = {1,3};//count
           ptrdiff_t stride[] = {1,1};//stride
           retval = nc_put_vars_float(ncid, rhid, start, count, stride, (const float*)data);
           if (retval != NC_NOERR) //error mesage
               ERR(retval);  // get into here error (retval == NC_EEDGE)

           n +=1;//a
       }
   }
```

I don't know,How should I fix this.
Please can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are facing?

Comment: in fact,my problem is i want to write a netcdf file,but i don't know how to do this, use "nc_put_vars_float"  let value to write into file by one by one  sorry my english